# I am not able to find my webparts after deploying them to sharepoint site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have add the .wsp package to a sharepoint site and then deployed it through SharePoint Central Management Web App.

It currently says deployed however I do not see it in my gallery.

Did I miss a step ?

Thanks,

---

Won't let me answer my own question :P 
But Was able to solve it:

ok so after some additional clicking around Central Management web app I found the disconnect. 
Here are the steps that finally worked

First Published a package of my solution

- Right click on project select publish
- Select folder where to save your .wsp file
- open up SharePoint powershell and execute Add-SPSolution [path to the wsp file]
- Open up SharePoint Central Management Web Application
- Select System Settings on the left side menu
- Find your solution and click deploy
- **Missing Part**
- Go on your sharepoint home site
- Under Site Actions go to Site Settings Page
- Look for Web Parts in Gallery Section
- On the Library Tools strip select Documents
- Click on New Document and a pop up list of New WebParts will appear scroll and find your web parts
- Check out the web parts from your solution click Populate Gallery 
  You should find your web part under the Misc. folder

This all assumes that you are an sp admin.
Hope it helps others.

Comment: What "steps" have you performed? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: using power shell I ran add-spsolutuiubs "[pathtowspfile]" then I went on Central management web app under the Manage Farm Solution and Clicked deploy on the solution that I just added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do this after deploying the solution

Activating the feature on the site, go to site actions-> site settings -> site collection features, activate your feature and then go to custom webparts under add webpart, it should be there now.

Comment: Thank you I was just writing the solution on my edit. Yes that was the issue.

Comment: I did not have to activate the feature, what is the importance to activate feature vs. just going under the web parts (Gallery) and adding them that way ?

Answer (score 0):

ok so after some additional clicking around Central Management web app I found the disconnect. Here are the steps that finally worked

- First Published a package of my solution
- Right click on project select publish
- Select folder where to save your .wsp file
- open up SharePoint powershell and execute Add-SPSolution [path to the
  wsp file]
- Open up SharePoint Central Management Web Application
- Select System Settings on the left side menu
- Find your solution and click deploy
- **Missing Part**
- Go on your sharepoint home site
- Under Site Actions go to Site Settings Page
- Look for Web Parts in Gallery Section
- On the Library Tools strip select Documents
- Click on New Document and a pop up list of New WebParts will appear
  scroll and find your web parts
- Check out the web parts from your solution click Populate Gallery You
  should find your web part under the Misc. folder

This all assumes that you are an sp admin. Hope it helps others.